# How can I delay the function where my text appears so it doesn't join in with the appearing animation of my text box?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've searched around here and people say to use the setTimeout thing, but it doesn't seem to work on my script

The text_btn button is supposed to bring up the text box first, and located within the function of the button is my setTimeout, which should delay the addCharakter function. But it doesn't work at all for me

````
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

stop();

var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
var myString:String = "";
var counter:int = 0;
var delayTimer: Timer = new Timer(50);


text_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, depletehealth); //button to bring in text box
function depletehealth(event:MouseEvent):void {
    
    textbox.gotoAndPlay("in");
    delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addCharackter);
    delayTimer.start();
    setTimeout(addCharackter,3000);
}


function addCharackter( E:Event = null ):void{ //typing text animation that should be delayed a bit
        
        myString = "how dare you speak to me";
        var charackterToAdd:String = myString.charAt(counter);
        textbox_txt.appendText(charackterToAdd);
        counter++;
        if(counter == myString.length){
         delayTimer.stop();
        }
}```
````

Comment: What is **textbox_txt**? It is not defined in your code. You might be adding your text to something that does not even exists. On the other hand, you create **myTextField** but never use it. Other than that, your code is supposed to output that text into the **textbox_txt** within 1 second.

Comment: my apologies. **textbox_text** is the Instance name of the Text Box that is supposed output the text. As for **myTextField**, i actually was supposed to remove that since i already have the box where the text will appear. 

Is the placement of the Timeout function correct? Because it is still not delaying the **addcharackter** function. Ive input 9999 as the delay time and it still appears along with the textbox

Comment: You use **Timer** class there which appends the whole string long before **setTimeout** has chances to do any work.

Comment: Ohh i see.I used the **Timer** class just so i can simulate my text's animation like its typing itself per letter. How can i still delay the timing of text without compromising its animation?

Comment: Increase this value: **new Timer(50);** It is a timeout in milliseconds that defines, how often the **Timer**'s even handler is called per second.